# Change template of WordPress comment-page

Tags: paginate-comments-links

I want to show `the_content()` only in The first page of each post, and I don't want to show `the_content()` in comment-page when "Break comments into pages..." enabled.

Is there a Way?

### [image]

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For comment pages, the `WP_Query`-var `cpage` is set, telling us which comment page we're on, making it is possible to filter the content for comment pages like this:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'comment_page_hide_content');
function comment_page_hide_content($content) {
    global $wp_query;
    if ($wp_query->get('cpage') > 1){ // Greater than one, because 1 inducates the first comment page
        $content = "";
    }
    return $content;
}
```